# Move to Universal Analytics - how to send City, State, Country

Tags: google-analytics

For some reason City, State, Country now are not used in Universal Analytics

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/reference/gajs-analyticsjs

New version:

```
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
  'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required
  'affiliation': 'Acme Clothing',   // Affiliation or store name
  'revenue': '11.99',               // Grand Total
  'shipping': '5',                  // Shipping
  'tax': '1.29'                     // Tax
});
```

Old version:

```
_gaq.push(['_addTrans',
  '1234',           // Transaction ID. Required
  'Acme Clothing',  // Affiliation or store name
  '11.99',          // Total. Required
  '1.29',           // Tax
  '5',              // Shipping
  'San Jose',       // City
  'California',     // State or Province
  'USA'             // Country
]);
```

But how can I send City, State and Country now? Will Google calculate these variables for itself only?

Comment: This guy: http://misterphilip.com/universal-analytics/migration/ecommerce claims transaction geo info has been removed in UA and since it's no longer in the documentation I guess he is right. However as far as I can find out this info has only ever been visible in view filters so I guess it's no great loss, and  if you need it back you can alway use custom dimensons.

Comment: @EikePierstorff I think your comment should be an answer.