# Can't track E-Commerce shipping details using Google Analytics Measurement Protocol

Tags: google-analytics, measurement

I need to track E-Commerce data in my Google analytic account using measurement Protocol. In the request I need to send following data and those data need to be tracked in my account.

1. Billing City (utmtci)
2. Billing Region (utmtrg)
3. Billing Country (utmtco)

But when I tried to find the parameters for these using [enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ecomm/) I could not find any matching parameter. Please help if any one know whether I can track these using measurement protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been discussed (but not yet answered) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224322/move-to-universal-analytics-how-to-send-city-state-country) - basically it seems those fields have been deprecated.

I do not see that spelled out in the documentation, but those field do not appear in the parameter reference, not in the API (via the query explorer) and not in the GA user interface. If stuff is not part of the documentation it's pretty safe to assume that it is not there.

You can create custom dimensions in your property settings and send the geo information there.

Comment: Thanks @Eike Pierstorff